# Numerical solution of two nonlinear 3D equations

Tags: python, 3d, numeric

Hello people on the internet! 
I have two 3D equations that I want to solve simultaneously. They are of the form **F(x,y,z)=C** and **G(x,y,z)=0**. The solution of these equations are supposed to describe curves (maybe even areas in some regions, I am not sure) and I want to obtain a discrete set of numerical solutions that "sample" these lines. I tried searching for a while, but the methods directed at solving I stumbled upon only aim to find a single solution.

I thought about using a Grid on 3d space and just check the equations, however that forces me to loosen the conditions a bit. But in case (or in regions where) the solution is a curve, the points are supposed to resemble a curve after all.

For better reference, my functions are of the form:

[image: Functions for 3d System of equations]

with random parameters **c_i, d_i, k_i, phi_i**.
For tips I would prefer native python, but I am open to any possible solution. Any ideas appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to start by sampling those functions on a 3D grid containing the portion of the solution set you are interested.

Once you've identified which regions of the gird may contain potential solutions, you'll then use an iterative method to minimize the function (F(x)-C)^2 + (G(x))^2.

The key here is that you will do the iterative algorithm for each gird region you identified as "interesting." Each time, initializing the method with values laying inside the region of interest.

Note: Sorry for the poor notation.